# Issue with sm.OLS.from_formula('variable1 ~ variable2 + x ') with statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

If I run the function `advanced_stats(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'myFile.csv')[0].summary()` or `advanced_stats(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'myFile.csv')[0].pvalues` then the function below will output `file[independent]` and `file[dependent]` instead of the actual names `'one', 'two' or 'three'`
 I need to know the column name when the values are outputted. The calculation and code works perfectly but the labels are important because I use them as part of my dataframe. So, I need to know how I can output the title 'one' instead of `file[dependent]`.

```
def advanced_stats(categories, file):

    finalData = []
    for dependent in categories:
        for independent in categories:
            if dependent == independent:
                pass
            else:
                model = sm.OLS.from_formula('file[dependent] ~ file[independent] + age + sex + height', file).fit()
                finalData.append(model)

    return finalData
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `model` has a list `model.exog_names`, maybe you can replace the name in this list before appending it to the `finalData`: `model.exog_names[:] = [dependent if x=='file[dependent]' else x for x in model.exog_names]` (the same for independent). Does this work?

Comment: I attempted it, although it sadly didn't work.

Comment: You could use a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python's string formatting, I found the following to be the best solution that does not require `exog_names` and more for loops.

```
model = sm.OLS.from_formula('{} ~ {} + age + sex + height'.format(dependent, independent), file)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
model = sm.OLS.from_formula('file[dependent] ~ file[independent] + age + sex + height', file)
model.exog_names[:] = [dependent if x=='file[dependent]' else x for x in model.exog_names]
model.exog_names[:] = [independent if x=='file[independent]' else x for x in model.exog_names]
result = model.fit()
finalData.append(result)
```

Comment: I tried your method but I received the following error: AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'exog_names'

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly: `model = sm.OKS.from_formula(...)` **without** `.fit()` at the the end? This should return the model, not an OSLResults object.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to remove the .fit() function. Your code worked, thank you very much!